# Starfleet admirals on the Federation Council?

Tags: star-trek, federation

Why are Starfleet officers present in the Federation Council if it's a civilian body?

Comment: In which of the six live action television shows or thirteen movies of Star Trek were Starfleet Officers shown to be members of the Federation Council?

Comment: As Joe indicated, it would help immensely if you told us *what* scene, in *what* story (a movie, a TV episode, a Star Trek novel you've read, or whatever) you were reacting to. Then we could examine the evidence ourselves, and see if there really were active-duty Starfleet admirals presented as "serving on the Federation Council." As opposed to, for example, it appearing that they had been called in to give a special report *to* the members of the Council; perhaps seeking the Council's approval for a certain course of action.

Comment: I believe a few high-ranking officers are present in Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home & possibly The Undiscovered Country, however in retrospect they may have been there as observers.

Answer (score 1):

The Op did not specify which *Star Trek* productions depicted Starfleet officers in the Federation Council.

The United states Secretary of War was a position usually filled by civilian politicians.

John McAllister Schofield was a career regular army officer who became a general of United States Volunteers during the Civil War.  He was a regular army brigadier general from 1864 to 1869, major general from 1869 to 1895, and lieutenant general in 1895.  He was secretary of War from June I, 1868 to March 13, 1869.

George Marshall was a career regular army officer who became a five star general in the regular army, a lifetime appointment in 1946.  Marshall served as Secretary of State from January 21, 1947-January 20,1949 and US Secretary of Defense from September 21,1950 to September 12, 1951.

> When the early months of the Korean War showed how poorly prepared the Defense Department was, President Truman fired Secretary Louis A. Johnson and named Marshall as Secretary of Defense in September 1950. The appointment required a congressional waiver because the National Security Act of 1947 prohibited a uniformed military officer from serving in the post. This prohibition included Marshall since individuals promoted to General of the Army are not technically retired, but remain officially on active duty even after their active service has concluded. General Marshall was the first person to be granted such a waiver, with Defense Secretary James Mattis being the second to receive it. Marshall's main role as Secretary of Defense was to restore confidence and morale while rebuilding the armed forces following their post-World War II demobilization.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Marshall#Secretary_of_Defense[1]

> James Norman Mattis (born September 8, 1950) is an American veteran and former government official who served as the 26th United States Secretary of Defense from January 2017 through December 2018. A retired United States Marine Corps general, Mattis served in the Persian Gulf War, the War in Afghanistan, and the Iraq War.
>
> As Mattis retired from the military in 2013, his nomination required a waiver of the National Security Act of 1947, which requires a seven-year waiting period before retired military personnel can assume the role of Secretary of Defense.[89]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Mattis[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Mattis)

Alexander Haig was a regular army officer from 1947-1979 who was Deputy National security Advisor from June 1970 to January 4 1973 and Chief of Staff at the White House May 4 1973 to September 21 1974, both usually civilian positions.

[added 01-01-2020.  Arthur St. Claire (1736-1818) was a colonel in the Continental Army in 1776, promoted to brigadier general in 1776 and major general in 1777 to 1781?

As a civilian he was the President of the Continental Congress in 1787-1888, presiding when the Northwest Ordinance was passed.  St. Clair was then the governor of the Northwest Territory (Ohio, Indiana, Illinois, Michigan) from 1788-1902.

St. Clair was also the commanding officer of the United States Army with the rank of major general in 1791-1792, thus being both a high ranking civilian officer and a high ranking military officer at the same time.]

So military officers sometimes fill high civilian positions in the US government, and if I remember correctly that is more common in a lot of other countries.